# Flag Value of semget() function

Tags: c, system-calls, semaphore

`semget()` function is used for creating a semaphore set. It takes three arguments:

1. Key value of the semaphore.
2. Number of semaphores in the set.
3. Flag value. It decides access permissions and constrains of creating a semaphore.

In a code, the flag is chosen as zero like this:

```
semget(semid, 1, 0);
```

What does it mean to choose flag value is zero ? I searched it, but I could not find the answer. Is there anyone who know what it means ?

Answer (score 1):

IBM zOS [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rsemgt.htm) describe this:

> When semflg equals 0, the following applies:
>
> - If a semaphore identifier
>     has already been created with key earlier, and the calling process of
>     this semget() has read and/or write permissions to it, then semget()
>     returns the associated semaphore identifier.
> - If a semaphore identifier
>     has already been created with key earlier, and the calling process of
>     this semget() does not have read and/or write permissions to it, then
>     semget() returns-1 and sets errno to EACCES.
> - If a semaphore identifier
>     has not been created with key earlier, then semget() returns -1 and
>     sets errno to ENOENT.

Maybe some people will make loud about **zOS** but docs write following:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE # POSIX 
#include <sys/sem.h>

int semget(key_t key, int nsems, int semflg);
```

`_XOPEN_SOURCE` mean support X/Open and POSIX standards which most of UNIX-like systems supported (Linux, FreeBSD ...).

Summary from "The Linux Programming Interface" by  Michael Kerrisk (page 928). I'll write about `msgget` (get IPC message queue identifier. Behaviour of `flag` parameter for semaphore is the same) as in source.

Suppose that we need one message queue for IPC between processes of two or more users. All users in the same group. One user created message queue:

```
msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP);
                      /* rw-r----- */
```

An attempt by another user of the same group to obtain an identifier for this message in the same manner will be failed:

```
msgget(key, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

Because the another user doesn't have write permissions to this queue because he didn't create an queue.

*Workaround* is exists and it's pass **0** to `flag` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the flag value is zero, then the call is being used to obtain the ID of the existing set. At least on Linux, the manual page could make this a little more obvious. I've just fixed that, so that the manual page now says:

```
   The  semget() system call returns the System V semaphore set iden‐
   tifier associated with the argument key.  It may be used either to
   obtain  the identifier of a previously created set (when semflg is
   zero and key does not have the value IPC_PRIVATE), or to create  a
   new set.
```